# как найти максимальное значение в словаре python?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Найти три ключа с самыми высокими значениями в словаре

```
my_dict = {'a':500, 'b':5874, 'c': 560,'d':400, 'e':5874, 'f': 20}
```

Comment: что-то пробовали?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог -- галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 4):

```
my_dict = {'a':500, 'b':5874, 'c': 560,'d':400, 'e':5874, 'f': 20}

print(sorted(my_dict.values())[-3:])
```

Func:

```
lambda v, d: sorted(d.values())[-v:]
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в задании просят вернуть ключи с максимальным значениями, а этот код возвращает сами значения?

Answer (score 4):

Вот так вот для ключей+значений:

```
import heapq, operator

my_dict = {'a': 500, 'b': 5874, 'c': 560, 'd': 400, 'e': 5874, 'f': 20}

print(heapq.nlargest(3, my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Вот так вот только для ключей:

```
import heapq, operator

my_dict = {'a': 500, 'b': 5874, 'c': 560, 'd': 400, 'e': 5874, 'f': 20}

print(list(zip(*heapq.nlargest(3, my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))))[0])
```

Или проще:

```
import heapq

my_dict = {'a': 500, 'b': 5874, 'c': 560, 'd': 400, 'e': 5874, 'f': 20}

print(heapq.nlargest(3, my_dict, key=lambda k: my_dict[k]))
```